# Redux-Saga call() and put() in map

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I'm trying to make several requests using `all()` and `map()` functions and if result comes and have the expected shape, I want to call another action to save the result in my store.

Here's a part of my saga, but it's not working as expected - the `getAvailabilityRequest` is not executed.

```
   yield all(
    part1.map((p1) => {
      return part2.map((p2) => {
        return tld.map((t) => {
          const response =  call(getAvailabilityRequest, `${p1}${p2}.${t}`);
          if (response && isAvailabilityResult(response)) {
              const index: AvailabilityIndex = { part1: p1, part2: p2, tld: t };
              return put(setAvailabilityActionCreator({ index, item: response }));
            }
        });
      });
    })
  );
```

Also I've tried this

```
  const response = yield all(
    part1.map((p1) => {
      return part2.map((p2) => {
        return tld.map((t) => {
          return {index: { part1: p1, part2: p2, tld: t }, result: call(getAvailabilityRequest, `${p1}${p2}.${t}`)};
        });
      });
    })
  );
```

to keep the data about `index`, but still, `getAvailabilityRequest` is not being called.
Is there a way I can change the saga to get expected results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not *returning* the call so it can't be *yielded*. What's more important - `yield all` expects an array of functions that return *Promises*. Dispatching an action doesn't return a *Promise* and this is what you are doing here. `put` are a *non-blocking* calls.

I'd suggest you to *delegate* the logic to a separate generator function.

```
function* getAvailability(p1, p2, t) {
   try {
      const response = call(getAvailabilityRequest, `${p1}${p2}.${t}`);
      if (response && isAvailabilityResult(response)) {
          const index: AvailabilityIndex = { part1: p1, part2: p2, tld: t };
          yield put(setAvailabilityActionCreator({ index, item: response }));
      }
   } catch (error) {
     // error logic
   }
}
```

**Edit**: It seems like the nested `map` is an issue. `yield all` expects a flat array.

```
const calls = yield [];

yield part1.forEach((p1) => {
   part2.forEach((p2) => {
      tld.forEach((t) => {
         calls.push(call(getAvailabilityRequest, `${p1}${p2}.${t}`));
      });
   });
});


const response = yield all(calls);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still - the `getAvailability` function is not being called.
I've also tried adding `flat()` to the end of the first map(), to remove it's nesting, but that didn't help as well

Comment: @SergeiKlinov I did some tweaks, check the updated answer.

Comment: @kinguser Thanks, removing that nesting did help.